# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Push subscribing stopped from working

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to get push notifications working on a Worklight V6.0.0.1 app running on an Android 4.1.2 device.

The only error that I see is in the device LogCat:

> Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server

Here are a few lines prior to the error (with ids modified):

> 12-03 20:12:49.013: D/GCMBaseIntentService(7218): handleRegistration:
>   registrationId =
>   xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx,
>   error = null, unregistered = null
>
> 12-03 20:12:49.013:
>   D/GCMRegistrar(7218): resetting backoff for com.abc123
>
> 12-03 20:12:49.013: D/WLDroidGap(7218): Registered at the GCM server with
>   registration id
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx_xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
>
> 12-03 20:12:49.013: W/CordovaPlugin(7218): Attempted to send a second
>   callback for ID: Push12345678
>
> 12-03 20:12:49.013:
>   W/CordovaPlugin(7218): Result was:
>   "xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxs-xxxxxxxxxx_xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx-xxxx"
>
> 12-03 20:12:54.451: E/abc123(7218): Can't subscribe, notification
>   token is not updated on the server

I don't see any errors in the Worklight server log.  I have also tried turning on the com.worklight.integration.* trace flag, but I didn't see any additional error messages.

I have used the same `pushSender` `key` and `senderId` values in the past.

Are there any suggestions for things I can do to get more debug information on why this subscription request is failing?

Comment: What has changed in the application since it last work for you?

Comment: Idan, my apologies, I should have stated that I have used the same pushSender, key and senderId values in a different "pushNotification" app and that app still works.  Thanks!

Comment: have you found a solution to that problem? I have the same thing here