# IBM Workilght 6.0 - Cannot subscribe to push notification after logout

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm facing a subscription problem in a Worklight-based app with the Android environment.

The first time, when the application does the subscription, things are OK, but when unsubscribing and logging-out and then trying to login againand subscribe the user for the second time,  things go wrong.

Normally, and as shown in the log, the notification is supported and the user is unsubscribed. However I get this error:

> Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server

This is the LogCat:

> 12-31 09:41:17.220: D/CordovaLog(6293): isSupported : true 12-31
>   09:41:17.220: D/CordovaLog(6293): isSubscribed : false 12-31
>   09:41:17.220: E/CPCapp(6293): Can't subscribe, notification token is
>   not updated on the server 12-31 09:41:17.295: D/CPCapp(6293): Clearing
>   notification subscriptions. 12-31 09:41:17.300: D/CPCapp(6293): Send
>   new server notification token id. 12-31 09:41:17.300:
>   D/GCMRegistrar(6293): resetting backoff for com.CPCapp 12-31
>   09:41:17.300: V/GCMRegistrar(6293): Registering app APP_PACKAGE of
>   senders SENDER_NUMBER

I saw this question which may be related to the same issue but not sure it is: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Push subscribing stopped from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365262/ibm-worklight-6-0-push-subscribing-stopped-from-working)

I'm using Worklight 6.0, Android 4.1 and AdapterAuthentication with endUser as parameter.

Comment: Can you reproduce this same behavior using the **sample push notifications project**? login > subscribe > send push > unsubscribe > logout > login > subscribe. Does the second subscription attempt fail or succeed?

Comment: I did the process with the **sample push notification project** and I putted this code in the logout function `WL.Client.logout('PushAppRealm', {onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp});` after the seconde login, the `subscribe`button still **disabled** I think the `onReadyToSubscribe` is not invoked. that's why the user cannot subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, I have also tested this with the [push notifications sample project in Worklight 6.1.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced).

The reason why the app is not able to subscribe/unsubscribe after logging out and logging back may be related to this CordovaPlugin message appearing in LogCat:

> 01-02 15:20:13.530: W/CordovaPlugin(27846): Attempted to send a second
>   callback for ID: Push66817967 01-02 15:20:13.530:
>   W/CordovaPlugin(27846): Result was:
>   "APA91bHDrNHkbBwVtdrjqHj-KNGnmlMue2heoK7dGIHEnQW6ORJpaFregHRKs9qjUOsuIGue9r3ZfbQvwCQtgGZH9MI7U8gbXmrkrtYgyslHNlQemMjAxK40CuRO78Xw9sTnlrzvEFkA4oZ3PUYLgqMz2fnWsKLd0w"

I have opened a defect and it will be investigated.

There is one workaround that I have come up with and that worked for me, by doing the following, but do note:

- This workaorund should be done **only** for the sake of minimal app flow testing until the problem is resolved.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="logoutButton" value="Logout" onclick="logoutFromApp();" />
```

**JavaScript:**
See the added `WL.Client.connect` after `WL.Client.reloadApp`.

```
function logoutFromApp() {
    WL.Client.logout("PushAppRealm", {
        onSuccess: function() {
            WL.Client.reloadApp(); 
            WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: successfulConnect, onFailure: failedConnect});
        },
        onFailure: function() { 
            alert ("Failed logging out");}
        }
    );
}

function successfulConnect() {
    WL.Logger.debug ("Connect state: success");
}

function failedConnect() {
    WL.Logger.debug ("Connect state: failure");
}
```

Comment: As you recommended, I did an investigation with **Wireshark** and I noticed that the `JSESSIONID`is not updated, also I tried your code by adding  `WL.Client.connect' but didn't work also. What did you mean by **This should not be done in a production environment** ?

Comment: That my code above is not a solution (it worked for me...); Anyway, jut wait until I update my answer soon...

Comment: @ghostrider3, see my edited answer above. Please tell me: are you an IBM customer or business partner?

Comment: Thank you @Idan, I'm a business partner

Comment: @ghostrider3, what is the name of your company? Who is customer? Is it an IBM customer?

Comment: @ghostrider3. This has been fixed for the next version of Worklight. If you have a customer application that requires this fix, open a PMR and it will be back-ported to the Worklight version you are using.

Comment: Thanks Idan, I wasn't able to open a PMR But I reported it for the concerned party and it will do the whole stuff.

Comment: Make sure they mention this question.